# Is there a law about mixing alcohol in eatables in India

Tags: india, alcohol

I am considering starting a shack/small restaurant. I am considering adding items that will have alcohol mixed in them.

What is the law around this in India? I am not considering selling alcohol. It would only be mixed in small amounts.

If there is a law around it, what is it?